# Npm unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to do npm install on a GitHub project that I have pulled. After a while, it gives me this npm login error.

[image]

After the error, I have run npm login and successfully login with my credentials but it keeps giving me the same error.

I have also uninstalled node and npm and installed them again, updated them to the latest versions, deleted information inside the .npmrc file and nothing seems to work.

I have tried to do npm install with other GitHub projects and it is working fine. I have no idea why this is happening

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

Figure out after a couple of days deleting package-lock.json make it work.